# Cypher returns duplicated results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This query is created to return the stats for a visited URL. But unfortunately, most of the time I get unwanted results. For example, if a link has 80 visits (80 VISIT nodes), the results array would have more than 650 items in it.

This is the query:

```
'MATCH (l:URL { id: $id })<-[:CREATED]-(u:USER { email: $email }) ' +
`${domain ? 'MATCH (l)-[:USES]->(domain { name: $domain })' : ''}` +
'MATCH (v)-[:VISITED]->(l) ' +
'MATCH (v)-[:BROWSED_BY]->(b) ' +
'MATCH (v)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(c) ' +
'MATCH (v)-[:OS]->(o) ' +
'MATCH (v)-[:REFERRED_BY]->(r) ' +
'MATCH (v)-[:VISITED_IN]->(d) ' +
'RETURN l, b.browser AS browser, c.country AS country,' +
`${domain ? 'domain.name AS domain, ' : ''}` +
'o.os AS os, r.referrer AS referrer, d.date AS date ' +
'ORDER BY d.date DESC'
```

Also the project is open source, so the full code for queries can be found here:
https://github.com/thedevs-network/kutt/blob/a1d9796c7f5573c590752a1bd635f445e4a971b7/server/db/url.js#L339-L350

Comment: what is v ? not defined, no label and ... not returned. 
Is v useful ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that unless there is one of every node in your matches, you're going to get multiplicative results, as cross products are formed between the nodes that are found.

You may want to look through your results and determine where multiple results occur.

Here's one way you could test for multiple associated nodes per visit node, by aggregating on most of the other nodes in your query:

```
'MATCH (l:URL { id: $id })<-[:CREATED]-(u:USER { email: $email }) ' +
`${domain ? 'MATCH (l)-[:USES]->(domain { name: $domain })' : ''}` +
'MATCH (v)-[:VISITED]->(l) ' +
'MATCH (v)-[:VISITED_IN]->(d) ' +
'WITH l, v, u, `${domain ? 'domain, ' : ''}` ' +
'[(v)-[:BROWSED_BY]->(b) | b.browser] as browser ' +
'[(v)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(c) | c.country] as country ' +
'[(v)-[:OS]->(o) | o.os] as os ' +
'[(v)-[:REFERRED_BY]->(r) | r.referrer] as referrer ' +
'd.date as date ' +
'RETURN l, browser, country,' +
`${domain ? 'domain.name AS domain, ' : ''}` +
'os, referrer, date ' +
'ORDER BY date DESC'
```

See if the number of results changes. Look for lists that have more than one value. Or similar results occurring multiple times but on different dates.

EDIT

Now that you've confirmed there are duplications, we'll need to find out if this is because of duplicated nodes, or duplicated relationships.

Most likely this is due to duplicated relationships. You can check with this:

```
MATCH (v:VISIT)
WITH v, size((v)-[:OS]->()) as OS_count
RETURN count(v)
```

You can modify as you like to actually get the nodes with multiple :OS relationships, or check for other duplicated relationships.

Comment: Yes you were right, there are duplicated nodes: https://image.ibb.co/g18Ccn/Screenshot_20180305_221421.png. 

So I think the way I create the visit node is the problem. This is the code: https://github.com/thedevs-network/kutt/blob/a1d9796c7f5573c590752a1bd635f445e4a971b7/server/db/url.js#L70-L84

Comment: Okay, that's progress. Most likely you have duplicate relationships going out to the same node. I added a query that can get you the number of :VISIT nodes that have multiple :OS relationships.

Comment: You may also want to check if there are duplicates of certain nodes, such as the iOS node.

Comment: Yep, the relationships are duplicated, interestingly, the count is the same for all :BROWSED_BY, :OS and other nodes related to each visit node. https://image.ibb.co/jYzccn/Screenshot_20180305_230706.png. Any idea how to prevent this in the future?

Comment: also how to remove the duplicated relation, tried some answers here but they don't seem to work for me.